Trouble Highlighting IFCOPENINGELEMENTs in three.js 3D View
I'm utilizing the IFC loader to import an IFC file into three.js for 3D visualization. My current task involves highlighting all opening elements (IFCOPENINGELEMENT) in red within the 3D view. Below is the code snippet:
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { IFCLoader } from 'web-ifc-three/IFCLoader';
import { IFCOPENINGELEMENT } from 'web-ifc';

// Scene setup
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xaaaaaa);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 10;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
scene.add(light);

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const ifcLoader = new IFCLoader();
ifcLoader.ifcManager.setWasmPath('node_modules/web-ifc/');

ifcLoader.ifcManager.setOnProgress((event) => console.log(event));

const firstModel = true;

await ifcLoader.ifcManager.applyWebIfcConfig({
    COORDINATE_TO_ORIGIN: firstModel,
    USE_FAST_BOOLS: true
});

ifcLoader.load('mockup.ifc',
    async (ifcModel) => {
        console.log('IFC Model loaded:', ifcModel);
        const highlightMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, depthTest: false, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 });
        await highlightIFCElements(ifcModel, IFCOPENINGELEMENT, highlightMaterial);
        scene.add(ifcModel);
        animate();
    },
    (progress) => {
        console.log('Loading progress:', progress);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.error('Error loading IFC file:', error);
    }
);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

async function highlightIFCElements(ifcModel, typeNumber, material) {
    const ifcManager = ifcLoader.ifcManager;
    const modelID = ifcModel.modelID;

    const elements = await ifcManager.getAllItemsOfType(modelID, typeNumber, false);

    elements.forEach(elementID => {
        const subset = ifcManager.createSubset({
            modelID: modelID,
            ids: [elementID],
            material: material,
            scene: scene,
            removePrevious: true
        });
        console.log("subset",subset)
        if (subset) {
            subset.layers.set(1); 
            subset.renderOrder = 1;
            console.log('Highlighted element', elementID, subset);
        } else {
            console.log('Failed to create subset for ', elementID);
        }
    });
}

The method "highlightIFCElements" retrieves all the elements of type "IFCOPENINGELEMENT", but I am struggling to change the color of the element in the 3D view. Can someone help me with that?
